# Proof a limit property with induction

Tags: limits, proof-writing

I need to use induction to prove that for every integer $n ≥ $2 and every $n$ functions $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n$,

$$\lim_{x\to a} f_i(x)=L_i\,\,\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to a}\Biggl(\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i(x)\Biggr)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}L_i$$

I would appreciate if somebody can help me. Thank you.

Comment: I've posted a complete answer. However, before seeing it, try to do it by yourself. You need a basis step, like proving that for n = 2 the assertion holds; then, assuming that for n - 1 the assertion holds, prove it for n. Then you're done :-)

Comment: @uomoinverde Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case **$n = 2$**: trivially true, we have just $$\lim_{x \to a} f_1 + f_2=  \lim_{x \to a} f_1 + \lim_{x \to a} f_2 = L_1 + L_2$$.
**Inductive** step: let's assume that our assertion holds for $n - 1$, so we assume that $S := \lim_{x \to a} \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} f_i = \sum_{i = 1}^{n -1} L_i$ is true. Then,
$$
 \lim_{x \to a} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} f_i = \lim_{x \to a} \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} f_i + \lim_{x \to a} f_n = S + L_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} L_i
$$.